# Why is a bad practice to distribute the Debug version of the application in .NET?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, deployment, installation

Reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100947/how-can-i-have-different-properties-and-such-in-a-vs-2010-setup-project-for-the-f), in the first comment, @Cody Gray says:

> Erm, you know that you're not supposed
>   to redistribute the "Debug" version,
>   right?

I'm concerned about it. In Visual Studio, I usually develop my applications in Debug mode, and if I need to distribute the executable, all I do is zip the `.exe` and required `.dll` files (in `bin\Debug` folder).

Why is it a bad idea?

What is the difference between doing this and doing exactly the equivalent thing in Release mode?

**Edit:**
I asked this question time ago, but I just wanted to edit it to add a difference:

When using `Debug.Assert` in the code to test it, and compile in *Release Mode*, all those lines are gone, so that could be another difference.

Comment: They didn't just pull the names out of a hat. There are tons of different reasons, I don't really feel like listing them all. It's not "exactly the equivalent thing in Release mode" because you're compiling it an entirely different way. It seems to me that once you understand the terms, you'll have the answer to your question.

Comment: Any link/reference where to read the differences between compiling in Debug and Release mode?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on what kind of language you use to develop your program.  When you use C++, you get the overhead of /RTC and the Edit + Continue support.  They slow down the generated code by a great deal and make it likely your app crashes early on a StackOverflow if you use recursion.  The runtime exceptions you can get from the checking code can be hard to diagnose without a debugger.

If you use VB.NET then you'll easily have a unpluggable memory leak when you use the Debug build without a debugger.  A flaw in its Edit + Continue support code causes a WeakReference to be leaked for every instance of a class that contains a WithEvents event.  Your app eventually dies on an OutOfMemory exception.

If you use C# then not a heckofalot goes wrong, the JIT compiler is just prevented from generating optimized machine code and garbage collection isn't as efficient.  Your program will run slow and consume more memory than necessary.  This applies to VB.NET and C++/CLI as well.

Perf is usually foremost on a programmer's mind when writing code.  As such, shipping the debug build is a bit blasphemous.  A significant number of programs are however completely throttled by I/O, the disk, network card or the dbase server typically.  Raw cpu perf doesn't matter a great deal in that case.

Comment: Good response, I would have agreed with you entirely ten or fifteen years ago, but I would say that when I write code nowadays what is generally foremost is readability and maintainability. Now having said that I don't go out of my way to write slow code, but I do think that in general the compiler will do a pretty good job of optimising code for me. (Of course these are exceptions to this, I'm speaking generally.)

Answer (score 1):

I think performance is an issue, [this post has more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251797/asp-net-website-dll-debug-vs-release-version)

Answer (score 1):

A pure C# or VB.NET application may work on any machine with the right .NET framework redist being installed, but a C++ or C++/CLI application (or a mixed application) needs the VC redist package, which does not contain the debug versions of the needed libraries. Assuming that on your users PC Visual Studio is not installed, only a redistributable package, I would say you have the risk that a debug version of your program simply might not work there.

Answer (score 1):

There are legal reasons also -
Quote:
"Note that debug versions of an application are not redistributable and that none of the debug versions of various Visual C++ dynamic-link libraries (DLLs) are redistributable."
From [Redistributing Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0 Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260978%28v=VS.60%29.aspx)

And this is for Visual Studio 2010 "Determining Which DLLs to Redistribute": 
"You cannot redistribute all of the files that are included in Visual Studio; you are only permitted to redistribute the files that are specified in Redist.txt. Debug versions of applications and the various Visual C++ DLLs are not redistributable. From [Determining Which DLLs to Redistribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kche8ah%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding performance, I'd be interested to see some metrics about debug versus release.

Whilst I'm sure the metrics would vary depending on exactly what the application does, but my hunch is that most of the time the end user wouldn't know the difference.

Comment: I'm more interested in why people are so averse to shipping the Release build. Does it *cost* you more? Is it really any more trouble to switch your IDE settings and recompile? You should have a build server anyway, but even if you don't, this isn't a difficult task. I didn't understand the reason for asking the question initially, but this answer *really* makes me scratch my head. **Why do you care?** I suspect the performance difference is certainly perceptible, but even if it isn't. We're not talking about the tradeoff between maintainable/readable code and performance. This is basic stuff.

Comment: Well, I think it is entirely reasonable to ask why, presumably after weeks or months of development in Debug mode, you should suddenly flip a switch and build/ship with a different configuration. Why would you make such a change unless there was some kind of gain? And why is it unreasonable for someone to post a question asking what that gain is?